# React Native Expo: Read local file from assets folder

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, csv, expo

I am trying to read a [local CSV file](https://github.com/JosipDomazetDev/WienerLinienApp/blob/master/assets/wienerlinien.csv) that is in my projects assets folder **(**and not on the FS of the test device**)**.

[HomeScreen.tsx](https://github.com/JosipDomazetDev/WienerLinienApp/blob/master/screens/HomeScreen.tsx):

```js
useEffect(() => {
    Papa.parse(require('../assets/wienerlinien.csv'), {
        delimiter: ';',
        header: true,
        newline: "\r\n",
        complete: (result) => {
            console.log(result);
            // this just prints {data: Array(0), errors: Array(0), meta: {…}}
```

This code prints an empty object on Web and on Android I get a `Unable to resolve "../assets/wienerlinien.csv" from "screens\HomeScreen.tsx"`.

This confuses me because React Native was perfectly capable of finding and displaying a local image from the same folder like this:

```html
<Image source={require('../assets/profile.jpg')} style={styles.profileImage}/>
```

How do I access and parse my CSV file from the `assets` folder?

In case it matters the CSV looks like this (`assets/wienerlinien.csv`):

```
"HALTESTELLEN_ID";"TYP";"DIVA";"NAME";"GEMEINDE";"GEMEINDE_ID";"WGS84_LAT";"WGS84_LON";"STAND"
214460106;"stop";60200001;"Schrankenberggasse";"Wien";90001;48.1738010728644;16.3898072745249;""
214460107;"stop";60200002;"Achengasse";"Wien";90001;48.2845258075837;16.4488984539143;""
```